# Redirect admin to dashboard after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to redirect an admin user to the dashboard after he logs in. To achieve this, I've overriden the `redirectPath()` method that is located in `RedirectUsers` trait. Here is the code:

```php
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }

    // MODIFICATIONS ------------------------------
    if(request()->user()->hasRole('admin')){
        return '/dashboard';
    }
    // ENDMODIFICATIONS ---------------------------

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

### The problem

Dashboard redirection **works only in some cases**:

- At first login, the admin is redirected to the home page.
- At subsequent logins, the admin is redirected to the dashboard.
- But if `php artisan cache:clear` command is run, admin gets redirected to the home page again.

Why is this happening and how do I implement this functionality correctly?

Comment: I added an answer as another alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding `redirectPath()`, you can create `authenticated` method in your `AuthController.php`, it will be called if exists after user successfully authenticated:

```
class AuthController extends Controller

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    ...

    public function authenticated()
    {
        if(Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user()->hasRole('admin')){
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed

Comment: Never change anything on vendor files. It will cause issues later when you are updating the package

Comment: @geckob why you down vote my answer? who changed files on vendor folder? we are never changed anything on vendor folders, we are simply do changes on `AuthController.php` located in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth` that using `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` and `ThrottlesLogins` traits

Comment: @geckob you are too funny man! it seems that you don't know you can override trait's method by simply creating a method with the same name on you class.

Comment: @RifkiAriaGumelar: I was wrong then. I knew it is possible. But I thought you meant the other way around. But still, I don't think that is the way to do it. Can you please edit your answer so that I can revote. Now, it is locked

Comment: @geckob Yes probably not the best way, but I think I'm doing it correctly see line 114 on `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` class there is `if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated'))` and will call `authenticated()` method if exits instead of redirect the user after successfully authenticated.

Comment: @gekcob I've edited my answer to make it more clear for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

How about middleware.

Make a middleware named RedirectIfAdmin.

Then place it in to the Homecontroller __construct.

I think this maybe more like laravel thinking.

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER CHANGE ANYTHING ANY FILES IN VENDOR FOLDER!**

It will cause issues when you are trying to update the packages as it will overwrite everything that is old! Also, by default, git will not track any files inside vendor folder

Here is the **alternative** and how it supposed to work:

Add `$redirectTo` attribute in your `AuthController.php`

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

  protected $redirectTo = '/user/dashboard';

}
```

Then, in your controller, you can do something like this:

```
if(Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user()->hasRole('admin')){
    $this->redirectTo = '/dashboard'
}
```

**What will happen:**

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

Whenever any method calling `redirectPath` function, it will check if the attribute of `redirectPath` is exist or not. If exist, use the provided url instead. If not, use the default which is '/home`

Comment: I'm not changing anything in the vendor folder, but thanks for the advice anyway. I've tried this approach, as it is pointer out in my question, but sometimes it doesn't work

Comment: @AlexanderLomia: Really? I am more than happy to know when it does not working